# Bitbucket API 2.0 - list of private repositories

Tags: repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

It is possible to get all user repositories using Bitbucket API 2.0 including private repositories? When I use https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username} i got only public.

Comment: According to the docs this will return all repositories owned by the specified account. Are you definitely the owner of the repositories, if not you could try setting the role parameter appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved, just have to get access token from bitbucket and send GET to https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories with Authorization: Bearer {YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}.

Comment: How do you generate your access token? I find a explanation for ouath 2 but where do I find my client_id and the secret? See https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/

Comment: @kuzdu: You need to create a consumer as described in https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html 
The `client_id` is the Key of the consumer and the `secret` is the Secret of the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Because I got stuck, here a little complement @Łukasz Strzałka post.

To get an access token you have to create a consumer. It's described here https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html (Thanks @Łukasz Strzałka)

[image]

1. You have to go to your Team Account: Click on your user icon -> choose your Team -> Settings -> OAuth
2. Add a consumer. The minimum is to set a title and a callback URL. Then you will get a key and a secret.

curl in terminal

```
curl -X POST -u "your_key:your_secret" \
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=password \
-d username={username} -d password={password}
```

The response should be a token.

Comment: what callback URL should I use ?

Comment: Does not care at this point. Use your company url for example.